# Reactjs managing stateful children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a dynamic list of children, that are form inputs.

ex:

```
var FormRows = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
     return {
        rows: []
     }
   },
   createRows: function() {
      this.props.values.maps(value){
         rows.push(<FormRow ...handlers... ...props... value={value} />
      }
    },
    addNewRow{
        // add a new row 
    },
    render: function() {
     return (
        <div> 
          {this.state.rows}
        </div> 
     );
  });

  var FormRow = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
     return {
        value: this.props.value || null
     }
   },
    render: function() { 
        <input type='text' defaultValue={this.state.value} ...changeHandler ... }
    }

  });
```

This is a dumbed down version , but the idea, is a its a dynamic form, where the user can click a plus button to add a row, and a minus button, which will set the row to visibility to hidden.

This state is nested n levels deep. What is the best way to actually get the state out of the children, and submit the form? I can use 'ref' add a function to getFormValue(): { return this.state.value } to the FormRow button, but i'm not sure if thats the best practice way.

I find myself using this pattern quite often, an array of undetermined size of children, that need to pass the state up.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s not a dumb question at all, and a good example of using flux principals in React. Consider something like this:

```
var App

// The "model"
var Model = {
  values: ['foo', 'bar'],
  trigger: function() {
    App.forceUpdate()
    console.log(this.values)
  },
  update: function(value, index) {
    this.values[index] = value
    this.trigger()
  },
  add: function() {
    this.values.push('New Row')
    this.trigger()
  }
}   

var FormRows = React.createClass({
  addRow: function() {
    Model.add()
  },
  submit: function() {
    alert(Model.values);
  },
  render: function() {
    var rows = Model.values.map(function(value, index) {
      return <FormRow key={index} onChange={this.onChange} index={index} value={value} />
    }, this)
    return (
      <div>{rows}<button onClick={this.addRow}>Add row</button><button onClick={this.submit}>Submit form</button></div>
    )
  }
})

var FormRow = React.createClass({
  onChange: function(e) {
    Model.update(e.target.value, this.props.index)
  },
  render: function() { 
    return <input type='text' defaultValue={this.props.value} onChange={this.onChange} />
  }
});

App = React.render(<FormRows />, document.body)
```

I used a simplified model/event example using Array and `forceUpdate` but the point here is to let the model "own" the form data. The child components can then make API calls on that model and trigger a re-render of the entire App with the new data (Flux).

Then just use the model data on submit.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ekr41bzr/**

Comment: interesting. didn't know you could encapsulate the state like this and call methods on that model. I wish this was documented in the React documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Bind values of inputs to some model (for example build in Backbone or Flux) and on submit retrieve values from there, without touching inputs.